# In which namespace is the extension method EntityTypeConfiguration.MapSingleType

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement the following code to map a database to a POCO that has slightly different Property names then the corresponding columns, and a slightly different class name than the table name.

[image: map to single type]

[Here's the article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/23/entity-framework-4-code-first-custom-database-schema-mapping.aspx)

The problem is there is no method called MapSingleType. I have the following two methods available:

```
public EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> Map<TDerived>(Action<EntityMappingConfiguration<TDerived>> derivedTypeMapConfigurationAction) where TDerived : class, TEntityType;

public EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntityType> Map(Action<EntityMappingConfiguration<TEntityType>> entityMappingConfigurationAction);
```

However, I can't find any examples of how to use them and I'm hoping to find the MapSingleType method since that works perfect for the very large number of columns I have to map.

I have downloaded CTP4 [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8812)

And I am using EF 4.0.3

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using PlayingWithEF.DAL.CLS.Classes;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace PlayingWithEF.DAL.CLS.Context
{

    public class CLSContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Listing> Listings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Listing>().Map(...?)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using ILSpy I don't see any members named "MapSingleType".  Have you looked at the System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers?  They have an internal sealed TypeMapper (may not be useful).

The DBModelBuilder has a MapTypes(EdmModel model) method, but it is private...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to map each property individually:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Listing>()
   .Property(l => l.YourProperty)
   .HasColumnName("PropertyName");

modelBuilder.Entity<Listing>()
   .ToTable("TableName");
```

Comment: It seems you're right, this is the only way I've found to do it too. Seems strange that they got rid of such a short simple syntax in favor of one that requires more code, but meh. There's always data annotations I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use CTP4 and EF 4.0.3 together, they're different versions of the same library.

I believe this functionality was removed from the betas at some point, and is no longer in the shipping version.

Comment: Yep, I didn't realize, and later got some ambiguity exceptions